# Using Google App Engines memcache as EclipseLink L2 cache

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, jpa, eclipselink

I have noted that DataNucleus supports L2 caching using Google App Engine memcache but is that the only JPA implementation that supports that? My implementation is EclipseLink 2.4.2 but so far I have not been able to find any information on how to use memcache for L2 caching. Do I have to switch to DataNucleus?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't plug in your own L2 cache in EclipseLink. http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/CacheCoordination
EclipseLink does handle the L2 cache itself.
But perhaps I have missed something so far...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I was hoping that EclipseLink would support using GAE memcache as L2 cache in a similar way as DataNucleaus does (by setting "javax.cache" as the L2-type in persistence.xml as far as I've learned). How would you go about having a distributed L2 cache in Google App Engine with EclipseLink? Right now I'm faced with a situation where GAE instances keep separate L2 caches which causes inaccurate and inconsistent data to be displayed in my clients. Is my only option for fixing this to switch to DataNucleus (or the datastore).